# How to sort numpy array by row sum and extract top N rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

For example, given matrix

```
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

and top_n=3, it should return

```
array([[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

**This function should return a np.ndarray of shape (top_n, arr.shape[-1]), given the input 2D matrix arr.**

Here's what I tried:

```
def select_rows(arr, top_n):
    """
    This function selects the top_n rows that have the largest sum of entries
    """
    sel_rows = np.argsort(-arr,axis=1)[:top_n]
    
    return sel_rows
```

I also tried:

```
sel_rows = (-arr).argsort(axis=-1)[:, :top_n]
```

to no avail.

Comment: Casting the array to negative with `-` is less efficient that slicing the data at the end. For the small sample this isn't an issue, but casting all the values to negative in a large array will be somewhat slower, which is verified with a `%%timeit` test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this simple 1-liner `a[np.argsort(a.sum(axis=1))[:-top_n-1:-1]]`

`a.sum(axis=1)` sums along axis 1

`np.argsort(..., axis=0)` argsorts along axis 0 (`axis=0` is default option anyway so could be omitted)

`...[:-top_n-1:-1]` picks the last `top_n` indices in reverse order

`a[...]` then grabs the rows

### `%%timeit` comparison

```py
# data sample
a = np.random.randint(0, 101, (100000, 1000))

%%timeit
a[np.argsort(a.sum(axis=1))[:-3-1:-1]]
[out]:
9.73 ms ± 122 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
a[np.argsort(-a.sum(axis=1))[:3]]
[out]:
9.9 ms ± 303 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
sorted(a, key=lambda x: sum(x))[:-3-1:-1]
[out]:
1.04 s ± 36.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code almost works, but you need to compute the sum of each row before sorting. You can try this:

```
import numpy as np


top_n = 3
arr = np.array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

arr[np.argsort(-arr.sum(axis=1))[:top_n]]
```

It gives:

```
array([[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

Comment: The answer should explain that the purpose of the `-` is to reverse the order

Answer (score 0):

Without `numpy`, you can use the built-in function `sorted` combined with argument `key`:

```
sorted(A, key=lambda x: sum(x))[:-top_n-1:-1]
```

Comment: This implementation is highly inefficient and should not be used with numpy arrays. For an array, `np.random.randint(0, 101, (100000, 100))`, this is 107 times slower than the numpy implementations.